# How can i add hover button to the link

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, hover

[This](http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/) is my blog as you can see FUll Details link in the post so i want to change that to button

The below is my code I want to add hover button like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_hover)

```css
.readmorecontent a {
    color: #008800;
    float: center;
    
}
```

```html
<span class="readmorecontent"><a href="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html">Full Details→</a></span>
```

This is my actual code in theme or template

```
<span class='readmorecontent'><a expr:href='data:post.url'>Full Details&#8594;</a></span>

.readmorecontent a {
    color: #008800;
    float: center;

}
```

Comment: Why not copying and edit the code from the link you have posted?

Comment: iam not getting what you are asking

Comment: There is no such value as `float:center`...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: i changed because when i executed in stackoverflow editor it is shifting to right thats y i changed for better understanding i hope you got it

Comment: @C0dekid the answer you posted also worked this is what i looking to implement

Comment: Glad it could help you! @AnushkaReddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the codes from the link you have posted in your question.. So you could do something like this:

```css
.readmorecontent a {
    color: #008800;
    float: center; /* Error on this line */
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    color: #008800;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.readmorecontent a:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="readmorecontent"><a href="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html">Full Details→</a></span>
```

> Note: `float: center;` doesn't exists. Maybe you are looking for `margin: 0px auto;`?

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with transition:

```css
.readmorecontent a {
   background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4CAF50;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.readmorecontent a:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="readmorecontent"><a href="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html">Full Details→</a></span>
```

Comment: this is what iam looking for